# Custom Tags and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml-namespaces

I am building a web application which is supposed to be (on the development level) highly standardized.

To accomplish this i want to use custom namespace tags which in the sourse code appear as they do, but are modified by javascript depending on what they are.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alert($('sy\\:icon').attr('location'));
//-->
</script>

<sy:icon id="icon1" location="/path/to/icon"></sy:icon>
```

Now i have tested this and it does work.  What would happen in this example is the entire tag would be replaced by javascript with one or more tags and styles which are valid in html.

My only concern is how different browsers of various versions would respond to an invalid tag, even though it is about to be immediately replaced.

For the record, i am aware that using something like a `<div>` with a specific class for reference is the normal approach, however using a custom tag would both save space in the source code, and look a lot nicer in my opinion, im just concerned with the implications, if any.

Comment: Google offers `<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>` as the default option for its +1 button. I don't think they (Google) would do this if it weren't cross-browser.

Comment: HTML and browsers were designed with custom tags in mind. That's how the `<noscript>` tag works -- browsers that predate script support don't recognize the tag, so they just display the text inside the tag. If browsers didn't support unknown tags, they'd completely break on pages written for newer versions of HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess ill go ahead with it, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your custom namespace in the `<html>` tag [as described here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1453-Using-jQuery-With-Custom-XHTML-Attributes-And-Namespaces-To-Store-Data.htm). That blog author notes that it's cross-compatible between the various browsers, with IE support back to IE7, so you should be fine.

Comment: That only matters if you're using XHTML. If you're just using plain HTML, namespaces aren't necessary.

Comment: I only use xhtml, a plus I need the namespaces to also make the tag unique. I actually read that blog u linked, it demonstrates the use of custom attributes which are actually very hand